# Issue with Multiple Site Manager

Tags: multi-site-manager

I've gone through all the steps of installing and activating the Multiple Site Manager for EE. It was all pretty straight forward. Everything appeared to work correctly, but when I click the "Edit Sites," button at the top I'm sent to just a plain white screen. No errors or anything. From what I can tell the URL is correct, it points to the page "manage_sites".

Wasn't sure if anyone had a similar issue like this when using Multiple Site Manager.

Comment: And what versions of EE and MSM are you using?

Comment: I haven't tried anything in terms of debugging, because I'm not getting any sort of error message. The site is running v2.5.5 of ExpressionEngine, and the plugin I installed is version 2.1.7. It is obvious that the plugin installed as I'm able to select multiple sites in the dropdown at the top right. But when I click "edit sites" I'm just presented with a blank white screen. It happens so quick that it is as if nothing even attempts to load on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Your MSM and EE versions are incompatible.

- MSM 2.1.7 works with EE 2.9.0
- MSM 2.1.6 works with EE 2.7.0
- MSM 2.1.5 works with EE 2.6.0
- MSM 2.1.4 works with EE 2.5.0

You'll either need to upgrade your copy of EE (recommended), or contact EllisLab to get a copy of MSM 2.1.4.